# How to show $\mu$ is measure when $E_n^c$ is countable?

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $X$ be an uncountable set, let $\mathfrak{M}$ be the collection of all sets $E \subset X$ such that either $E$ or $E^c$ is at most countable ( i.e, finite or countable), and define $\mu(E)=0$ in the first case, $\mu(E)=1$ in the second. Prove that $\mu$ is  measure on $\mathfrak{M}?$

My attempt : Here to prove $\mu$  is measure mean that $\mu$ is countably additive on $\mathfrak{M}$

we have two cases

$1.$when $E_n$ is  countable

$2.$ when $E_n^c$ is  countable

Case $1.$ : let $E_1, E_2...$ be  a countable sequence  of pairwise disjoint element of $\mathfrak{M}$

then their union  is also countable

so we have the following inequality

$\mu(\bigcup E_n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(E_n)=0$

My doubt : How to show $\mu$  is measure when $E_n^c$ is countable ?

Comment: You have more than the two cases you described, because, in the sequence of sets $E_n$, some of the sets might be countable and others might have countable complements.

Comment: Whenever one of the $E_n$ has countable complement, the union has countable complement.

Comment: @Yuval u mean $\mu(\bigcup E_n^c)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(E_n^c)=0?$

Comment: Actually, in $E_1 E_2, ...$ there can be at most one $E_n$ with $E_n^c$ at most countable - otherwise $E_1, E_2, ...$ would not be pairwise disjoint. In that case $\sum_j\mu(E_j)=1$ and clearly $(\cup E_j)^c$ is also at most countable, thus $\mu(\cup E_j)=1$ as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F$ be a countable subset of $M.$

If every $f\in F$ is countable then $\cup F$ is countable so $$\cup F\in M \;\land\;\mu(\cup F)=0=\sum_{f\in F}0=\sum_{f\in F}\mu(f).$$ If there exists an uncountable $f_0\in F$ then

(i) since $f_0\in M,$ we have $\cup F\in M$ because $(\cup F)^c$ is a subset of the countable set $(f_0)^c,$ and

(ii) since $(\cup F)^c$ is countable by (i), we have $$\mu(\cup F)=\infty=\mu(f_0)\le\sum_{f\in F}\mu(f)\le \infty.$$